# Aside navigation height to footer, not in fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I am trying to create a page with an aside navigation panel that stretches the entire length of the page to the footer as show below:

[image]

But annoyingly this is as close as I can get and I can't figure out how to do this!
[image]

I am not trying to keep either the aside or footer elements fixed onto the screen I want the footer to appear as I scroll down.

Actual:

[image]

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My Website</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
          <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" />
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </div>
        </header>
        <aside>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <div id="content">
            <nav>
                <a href="pages/.html">Home</a>
            </nav>
            <article>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Aliquam ac tortor id leo facilisis 
                ultrices. In ac turpis non sem 
                pellentesque porttitor. Ut eu elit 
                non velit pretium posuere non vel 
                arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu 
                ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
                per inceptos himenaeos. Sed posuere 
                lacus tellus, vel tristique felis 
                condimentum sit amet. Aliquam convallis 
                pretium arcu, eu pretium nunc lacinia a. 
                In porttitor cursus mauris id facilisis. 
                Proin vitae placerat leo. Vestibulum 
                accumsan venenatis neque, viverra 
                fringilla lectus pellentesque eu. Fusce 
                convallis nulla eu enim sagittis, ut 
                dignissim turpis commodo. Morbi blandit 
                risus mi, in aliquam sem tincidunt dapibus. 
                Suspendisse quis diam tincidunt, accumsan 
                dui facilisis, semper erat. Sed venenatis 
                rutrum lacus, ac vehicula mi mattis sed.
            </article>
            <article>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Aliquam ac tortor id leo facilisis 
                ultrices. In ac turpis non sem 
                pellentesque porttitor. Ut eu elit 
                non velit pretium posuere non vel 
                arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu 
                ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
                per inceptos himenaeos. Sed posuere 
                lacus tellus, vel tristique felis 
                condimentum sit amet. Aliquam convallis 
                pretium arcu, eu pretium nunc lacinia a. 
                In porttitor cursus mauris id facilisis. 
                Proin vitae placerat leo. Vestibulum 
                accumsan venenatis neque, viverra 
                fringilla lectus pellentesque eu. Fusce 
                convallis nulla eu enim sagittis, ut 
                dignissim turpis commodo. Morbi blandit 
                risus mi, in aliquam sem tincidunt dapibus. 
                Suspendisse quis diam tincidunt, accumsan 
                dui facilisis, semper erat. Sed venenatis 
                rutrum lacus, ac vehicula mi mattis sed.
            </article>
            <footer>
                <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
            </footer>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    min-width: 700px;
}

header {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #66F;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #63F;
}

nav {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding-left:160px;
}

article {
    color: #03F;
    background-color: #69C;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 160px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #888;
}

#header {
    overflow: auto;
}

#header img {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}

#header h1 {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:160px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: use a `clear: both` style before your footer div.

Comment: @FrayneKonok the issue is with the aside element, I want it to reach the footer and stop but it is going on for the entire page. The footer is fine where it is.

Comment: okey then fixed the height of the `content` as `aside`. use min-height and max-height same and overflow may be scroll or hidden.

Comment: @Daedric do you want the aside to be fixed or scrolled?

Comment: @Aziz I want it to be where it is but just stop when it gets to the footer. I don't want it scrolled or fixed.

Comment: @Daedric any updates on your situation?

Comment: @Aziz I was in a hurry so I just ended up shortening the size and it works just fine. But thanks for the response, I appreciate it. I will reference this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS table layout to achieve your desired result.

**Basic Demo:**

```css
/* table layout */

#main {display: table; width: 100%;}

aside, #content {display: table-cell;}

/* just for demo styling */

* {margin: 0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

header, footer {background:lightblue;  padding: 1em;}

#content {padding:1em; background:lavender;}

aside {width: 140px; padding:1em; background:lightpink;}

p {margin-bottom:1em;}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

<div id="main">

  <aside>Aside Nav</aside>
  
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa quo autem cumque, fugit doloremque, architecto velit ducimus aspernatur labore? Suscipit dolorem nemo dolore quae blanditiis distinctio ullam reiciendis, deserunt fuga.</p>
    <p>Iusto facere aperiam natus id possimus porro minima dolor vel? Quo sequi ullam vero voluptas. Inventore cum nostrum quaerat nemo quia, nesciunt corrupti, officiis, ut totam vitae, eius reprehenderit saepe?</p>
    <p>Fugiat nobis laboriosam quis, explicabo, architecto doloremque dolores. Quas at delectus cum porro ullam quae. Nisi aspernatur esse voluptatem accusantium obcaecati quaerat natus placeat, voluptatum ratione fugit, cumque, est quis.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/u51m1m13/)

This works by wrapping `aside` and `#content` in a common parent `#main`. The parent gets `display: table; width:100%` styling while the children are set to be `table-cells` (`display:table-cells`)

HTML Structure in a nutshell:

> header + ( #main > aside + #content ) + footer

Comment: jsFiddle of your original code with my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/6zh3nupz/

Answer (score 0):

Look im NO expert on css or html, but i THINK you could do this with grid. You could set the grod-template-columns to have 2 columns with auto, and 2 rows, and set the footer with a span: 2; on the second row. Poor explanation i know, but you can check out this amazing video by Kevin Powell where he explains grid and grid-template-columns and areas and span, and you will learn a lot.
Here is the link, hope it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU&ab_channel=KevinPowell

*I realize as i post this that this post is from 6 years ago, but still maybe it can help someone :D

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32009902)